# I am getting error while writing query in db2 sql. I need to have a CASE with 3 conditions

Tags: sql, db2

Here is my query :

```
select CASE IF(DATE(Stud40.Start_DT) > '0001-01-01') 
  THEN Stud40.Start_DT
    ELSE IF(Stud40.Start_DT IS NULL) 
        THEN Stud50.Start_DT 
           ELSE Stud.Start_DT END AS "Stud_joining_DT",
```

My error is :

```
SQL Error [42601]: ILLEGAL SYMBOL ">". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE:. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.9.78
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `case`:

```
select (case when date(Stud40.Start_DT) > '0001-01-01'
             then Stud40.Start_DT
             when Stud40.Start_DT IS NULL
             then Stud50.Start_DT 
             else Stud.Start_DT 
        end) as " Stud_joining_DT ",
```

Why would you put spaces in the column alias?

Comment: Your parentheses don't match up

Comment: 2 open parenthesis and 4 close parenthesis?

Comment: Sorry @Gordon, spaces in the alias was a typo

Comment: @Gordon, I didn't understand your solution, could you please recheck your parantheses

Comment: @GKr297 . . . The parentheses balance in this answer.